# Orbeon bug when xf:range initialy hidden

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to use the xf:range control in Orbeon since the form I'm making requires a slider.
This is possible if the range control is visible when the form is rendered.
In case the range was initially hidden and then becomes visible after a specific condition is met, all controls after it aren't rendered properly.

Is this a known bug? Is there a way to solve this or to implement a workaround?

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         fr:data-format-version="4.0.0">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title/>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <min>1</min>
                    <max>10</max>
                    <range>0</range>
                    <range-output/>
                    <value/>
                </section-1>
                <section-2>
                    <min2>1</min2>
                    <max2>10</max2>
                    <visible-value2/>
                    <range2>0</range2>
                    <value2/>
                </section-2>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="min-bind" name="min" ref="min"/>
                <xf:bind id="range-output-bind" ref="range-output" name="range-output"/>
                <xf:bind id="range-bind" ref="range" name="range" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                <xf:bind id="max-bind" ref="max" name="max" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                <xf:bind id="value-bind" ref="value" name="value"
                         calculate="round(($max - $min) * $range + $min)"/>
            </xf:bind>
            <xf:bind id="section-2-bind" ref="section-2" name="section-2" relevant="$value &gt; 5">
                <xf:bind id="min2-bind" name="min2" ref="min2"/>
                <xf:bind id="max2-bind" ref="max2" name="max2" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                <xf:bind id="range2-bind" ref="range2" name="range2" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                <xf:bind id="value2-bind" ref="value2" name="value2"
                         calculate="round(($max2 - $min2) * $range2 + $min2)"/>
                <xf:bind id="visible-value2-bind" ref="visible-value2" name="visible-value2"
                         xxf:whitespace="trim"
                         calculate="round(($max2 - $min2) * $range2 + $min2)"/>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>banking</application-name>
                <form-name>test</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en"/>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <min2>
                        <label>min</label>
                        <hint/>

                    </min2>
                    <max2>
                        <label>max</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </max2>
                    <visible-value2>
                        <label>visible value</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </visible-value2>
                    <range2>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                    </range2>
                    <value2>
                        <label>not rendered value</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </value2>
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Default Section</label>
                    </section-1>
                    <section-2>
                        <label>Hidden section</label>
                    </section-2>
                    <min>
                        <label>min</label>
                        <hint/>

                    </min>
                    <max>
                        <label>max</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </max>
                    <range>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                    </range>
                    <range-output>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                    </range-output>
                    <value>
                        <label>value</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </value>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid id="grid-1-grid">
                    <fr:c y="1" x="1" w="6">
                            <xf:input id="min-control" bind="min-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/min/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/min/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

                            </xf:input>
                        </fr:c>
                    <fr:c y="1" x="7" w="6">
                        <xf:input id="max-control" bind="max-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/max/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/max/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                        </xf:input>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="1" y="2" w="6">
                        <xf:range id="range-control" bind="range-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/range/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/range/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                        </xf:range>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="7" y="2" w="6">
                        <xf:output id="range-output-control" bind="range-output-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/range-output/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/range-output/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                        </xf:output>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="1" y="3" w="6">
                        <xf:output id="value-control" bind="value-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                        </xf:output>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="7" y="3" w="6"/>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
            <fr:section id="section-2-section" bind="section-2-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-2/label"/>
                <fr:grid id="grid-2-grid">
                    <fr:c x="1" y="1" w="6">
                        <xf:input id="min2-control" bind="min2-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/min2/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/min2/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                            </xf:input>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="7" y="1" w="6">
                        <xf:input id="max2-control" bind="max2-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/max2/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/max2/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>



                        </xf:input>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="1" y="2" w="6">
                        <xf:input id="visible-value2-control" bind="visible-value2-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/visible-value2/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/visible-value2/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                        </xf:input>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="7" y="2" w="6"/>
                    <fr:c x="1" y="3" w="6">
                        <xf:range id="range2-control" bind="range2-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/range2/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/range2/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>



                        </xf:range>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="7" y="3" w="6"/>
                    <fr:c x="1" y="4" w="6">
                        <xf:output id="value2-control" bind="value2-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/value2/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/value2/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>



                        </xf:output>
                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="7" y="4" w="6"/>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question below. Regarding the low priority of this issue, if you are a customer, I would encourage you to contact support, as this might have an impact on prioritization ;).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is a bug, and you can follow [issue #4131](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4131) if you want to track this. Note however that the range control currently isn't available in Form Builder, and so one would only hit this problem if they were to edit the source of the form, and explicitly change a control to an `xf:range`, so this is most likely a pretty low priority issue at this point.